# start-stop-daemon starting multiple processes

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to use start-stop-daemon to start a process that runs in the background. To my knowledge, start-stop-daemon is supposed to prevent a second process from being started if one is already running. The script I am running is rather simple for now:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    date > /home/pi/test/test.txt
    sleep 10
done
```

I am starting the script using `start-stop-daemon --start -v -b -m --pidfile /var/run/test.pid --exec /home/pi/test/test.sh`

I am able to successfully stop the script using `start-stop-daemon --stop -v --pidfile /var/run/test.pid`

However, if I run the start command twice, it will start two processes, instead of just one that I was expecting. Does the start command check the pid file before starting the process, or is there something else that needs to be done for that to happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [man page of **start-stop-daemon**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html) contains a special warning on the usage of the **--exec** option with scripts.

> **-x**, **--exec** *executable*
>
> Check for processes that are instances of this executable. The executable
>   argument  should be an  absolute  pathname. **Note:** *this might not work as
>   intended with interpreted scripts*, as the executable will point to the
>   interpreter.

When you run a script, the process that is actually launched is the interpreter noted in the shebang line of the script. This confuses the **start-stop-daemon** utility.

BTW, you can use the **-t** option to debug that kind of issues with **start-stop-daemon**.

Comment: Using `--startas` instead of `--exec` worked, as it was no longer trying to match the executable. Thank you!

Comment: @engineAL - your comment should be part of the answer! Big help, thank you!